# Error from server: code=1300 [Replica(s) failed to execute read] message="Operation failed

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Getting the below error while fetching 50k records from Cassandra using Python.

Any suggestions please?

Error from server: code=1300 [Replica(s) failed to execute read] message="Operation failed - received 0 responses and 1 failures" info={'consistency': 'LOCAL_ONE', 'required_responses': 1, 'received_responses': 0, 'failures': 1}

Answer (score 2):

This is hard to answer without seeing your query.  By the looks of the error message, it would seem that your `WHERE` clause filters are not restrictive enough.  Cassandra works great for running thousands of operations/second, pulling back small result sets.  But one query for 50k rows?  Not so much.  Especially when the rows are across multiple partitions.

In Cassandra you need to design your tables to support your queries.  When you don't do that, multiple nodes get contacted, and one node ends up coordinating the operation and building the entire result set itself.  When it gets too big (50k) it times-out, which is likely what is happening to you.

Break your query up into smaller queries to ensure that each can be completed by a single node.  A good way to do this is to have each key-based query be its own thread, limit the number of threads in-flight, and `await` them with listenable futures.

Answer (score 0):

Which fields concern your query. You have to index those areas.
For example;

```
create index target_image_index
   on target_image (field name);
```